# source code pointing to different php version on different server

Tags: linux, php

I was just wondering if it is possible to "Compile" the same php source with different PHP versions.

Let say, source code hosted on Server "A" with `php 5.4`, I can test the same source code without hosting on Server "B"(php 5.5) , but just by pointing Server's A source code to Server B .

is it possible ?
I know I can achieve this by maintaining two different php version on same server, but this is what I don't want .

Answer (score 2):

You could mount the directory tree containing the source code on A on the B server using for example NFS.

You could have your source config management system push changes to the B server.

You could have your CI solution push the changes from A to B.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, first one seems most promising as I dont want any GIT or VCS to push ( sync ) code between servers